# How to debug mobile website not working, and/or add javascript polyfill for safari browser?

Tags: javascript, css, html, modernizr, polyfills

I'm not 100% sure of the question I should be asking, so here's what I want done...

**Overview:**

I'm testing a website I made in html5/css3 on an old ipod touch 4th gen with the safari browser. It doesn't work on that device, so I think I need a polyfill or something to debug it so I can see what's going on. But I can visit other modern websites and they work fine, like the youtube desktop version. The ipod hasn't had support/updates in a long time, it's iOS 6.1.6, and as far as I'm aware it still uses html4, not 5. Why? Because html5 was released as w3c reccomendation in october 2014 *(or so wikipedia says),* while iOS 6.1.6 was released feb 2014 *(thus I think it still might use html4).*

**The problems I get:**

The only thing that shows when I visit on that device is the background color, and an svg image that's inside a `<div>` which has it's css set to `background-image: url(img-vid/some_svg.svg);`. Nothing else shows up. No `<nav>`'s, nothing, not even regular `<p>`'s or `<h1>/etc` tags, and many of those tags aren't even nested in any html5 tags. And even weirder is that div with the image in it is at the very bottom on the html code, right above `</body>`.

**What I tried:**

I tried using the following css trick to hopefully be able to see those elements render as block instead of inline. But that didn't work either:

```
header, section, footer, aside, nav, main, article, figure { display: block; }
```

If I check the site on a cheap $20 smartphone from walmart with the chrome browser, it works perfectly with all the @media queries. Everything is perfect as it was made to be. But not on the older ipod touch with it's safari browser.

**Closing statement:**

Is there some test I can run to see what is required for me to make it work? Do I need a polyfill? Are there any debug tools for this? Does anyone know how to add a polyfill? Is my ipod touch just bugged??.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to debug it as explained here: https://adao.co.uk/blog/inspect-element-on-safari-on-iphone-mobile/

This allows you to inspect the rendered elements as well as view the developer console.